# Change existing column to have a default value in migration

Tags: laravel

I have a column in text and I need to make it contain a default value, how should the change be made using migration?

Migration create Table

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateExperienceSettingsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('experience_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->uuid('experience_id');
            $table->boolean('schedule_required');
            $table->boolean('voucher_print');
            $table->boolean('address_required');
            $table->boolean('automatic_refund');
            $table->boolean('show_partner_discount');
            $table->boolean('branch_required')->default(false);
            $table->text('email_validation_user')->nullable();
            $table->text('email_validation_partner')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('experience_id')->references('id')->on('experiences')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('experience_settings');
    }
}
```

Migration update change value in column

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class ChangeEmailValidationUserDefaultValue extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('experience_settings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('email_validation_user')->default('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised')->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But when doing php artisan migrate and inserting the migration is not inserting the data with default value in column mysql.

Comment: Do you mean it's not changing the schema or it does not populate the `email_validation_user` column with the default data for existing records? If the latter, it won't do that automatically. You will only see the results of the change for newly created records. For the existing records you will have to do it manually.

Comment: does not change the schema, it must have a default value for the next records inserted. @ChrisCynarski

Comment: Check if it cleared NULLABLE flag from the column definition. It's the only thing that comes to my mind. It should work as intended otherwise.

Comment: The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#modifying-columns) also says you must have `doctrine/dbal` installed, do you ? I have no idea if it is going to error out of silently fail if not installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only add librery doctrine/dbal and run migration

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

this should work for you.